# How to find which file is affected by fsck error?

Tags: freebsd, fsck

Running `fsck` on a freeBSD ufs file system yield some block and sector errors. Usually running it twice or three time would fix and repair the problem. I ran it many times, and the problem persists.

How can I find the bad/broken files that `fsck` didn't succeed to repair?
in order to delete them from the file system

Comment: It would be useful if you could give more detail on the particular errors you are seeing. However, errors like this can be a sign of a failing disk.

Comment: fsck doesn't really repair files.  it checks and repairs the consistency of the filesystem itself (i.e. metadata, directories, dangling inodes, etc).  if you want a filesystem that can repair files then you should use zfs with either mirrored or raid-z pools.

Comment: In some cases fsck will give an error message containing the inode number (UPPERCASE ERROR TEXT I=inode-number).  You can find out what file it is using the find(1) command: find / -inum inode-number.